# nodejs net server работа с большими пакетами

Tags: node.js, сервер

Вообщем история такая!
Пишу на nodejs не большой сервер и столкнулся с такой проблемой.
Клиент может отправить на сервер большой пакет, который логично приходит по частям.
Как понять что передача была завершена?

```js
const net = require('net');

const server = net.createServer();

server.on('connection',function(socket){
    socket.on('data',function(data){
        let bread = socket.bytesRead;
        let bwrite = socket.bytesWritten;

        console.log('Bytes read : ' + bread);
        console.log('Bytes written : ' + bwrite);  
        //При большом пакете, событие срабатывает на каждую часть пакета
    });
});
server.listen(3001, '127.0.0.1');
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-stream . Можно в начале файла указывать сколько будет частей и обрабатывать это. Либо использовать библиотеку выше

Comment: Спасибо за идею, я правда за место количество пакетов, добавил общий размер в байтах.